# Apache proxying webRTC server

Tags: apache, websocket, proxy, webrtc, reverse-proxy

I have a front facing Apache server. I setup a Signaling server behind it for webRTC.
I made a seperate DNS name for it, just to simplify things, but I still didn't have any luck with the Apache configuration. I made a seperate file for it called signaling.conf.
I have enabled:
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
a2enmod proxy_wstunnel

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerName si******s.com

ProxyRequests on
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "http"

ProxyPass "/" "http://192.168.1.72/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://192.168.1.72/"

# Enable proxying Websocket requests to the standalone signaling server

 RewriteEngine On
# Websocket connections from the clients.
RewriteRule ^/standalone-signaling/spreed$ - [L]
# Backend connections from Nextcloud.
RewriteRule ^/standalone-signaling/api/(.*) http://192.168.1.72:8080/api/$1 [L,P]
```

It is working with the local ip of the second server. With this I can reach the nginx server default page from outside, but my application still only give me a 503.

Some help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late but I am coming with a solution maybe for others who ended up in this thread. Apache is working with the TCP protocol. webRTC server is mostly relying on UDP protocol.

But there is a solution and comes within linux so you will not need any other proxies or server software. It is called iptables !

[Source here](https://bobcares.com/blog/iptables-udp-port-forwarding/)